# Как учитывать запросы к геокодеру Яндекс.Карт?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

В условиях использования Яндекс.Карт написано
 — в бесплатном API есть ограничение - в сутки можно делать не более 25К запросов к геокодеру.

Не хочется чтобы блокировали неожиданно, по этому вопрос:
Можно ли каким то способом учитывать запросы к геокодеру и выводить их, скажем, на экран или в базу для контроля?

Comment: Вы всегда можете сохранять количество обращений к геокодеру на своей стороне, в чём проблема?

Comment: проблем в том что я не знаю как, по этому и спрашиваю :-)

Comment: А вы делаете запросы из браузера или из сервера?

Comment: запрос делается из браузера

Comment: @Monitorkin, на своем сервере разместите скрипт, который будет принимать запросы со страниц вашего сайта, отправлять эти запросы яндексу, получать ответы от него, кэшировать ответы на сервере и отдавать их пользователям. В нем и считать можно.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас у Яндекса есть [API Кабинета разработчика](https://yandex.ru/dev/developer-help/doc/api/auth.html). Обратите внимание, что у HTTP-геокодера теперь отдельный лимит на 1000 запросов в сутки (service: apimaps_http_geocoder_daily), лимит JS API остался прежним — 25 000 (service: apimaps_total_daily).

Статистика обновляется практически в риалтайм (0-15 минут).

Comment: К сожалению яндекс карты не подходят из-за своей политики. Приложение НЕ в общем доступе, а цены заоблачные для небоьшой компании.